# Apt-Mirror from existing local mirror

Tags: apt, updates, apt-mirror

I am looking at creating a chain of local Apt mirrors through our various security zones and am wondering if it is technically feasible and if so what may some of the pit falls be?

Something like this:

Zone 1 -> Mirrors from Public - Daily Sync
Zone 2 -> Mirrors from Zone 1 - Daily Sync
Zone 3 -> Mirrors from Zone 2 - Weekly Sync
Clients receive updates from Zone 3

I am intending on excluding all sources and backports and have allocated 300gb per mirror. Initially this will only cater to 18.04 LTS but may require additional older versions.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be perfectly okay to chain the apt repositories, and also ok for them to update every n days (cron can be used for this).  I also see no pitfals other than synchronization.  300 GB is more than enough (mine mirror takes ~150 GB for multiverse, backports and security of bionic/18.04). EDIT: repo on EOL uses ~250 GB.

## Synchronization

Since you will use cron for updating your repos, the best you can is to trigger synchronization at X:00 hour in public zone, at X+1 hour in your first zone, and so on.  This is in order to get the latest updates to your most-secured zone asap (within one synchronization cascade).  If you try to sync the zones in the oposite order (the public syncs as the last) you will have to wait **days** for the arrival of your critical updates to your highest-security zone.

#### Your architecture

Public | Zone 1 | Zone 2 | ...

#### Example cron configs

Create crons as "apt-mirror" user:

```
sudo -u apt-mirror crontab -e
```

in the appropriate mirror:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0  0   *   *   *    /usr/bin/apt-mirror     # in public mirror
0  1   *   *   *    /usr/bin/apt-mirror     # in zone 1 mirror
0  2   *   *   *    /usr/bin/apt-mirror     # in zone 2 mirror
0  3   *   *   1    /usr/bin/apt-mirror     # in zone 3 mirror, weekly
```

Note, that the fresh updates will "flow" as in a waterfall, from one mirror deeper into the zones to the other mirror.  In the morning you will have the fresh updates in the deepest zone ready to install.

## Install at the mirror-server

All you need on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 is actually this: https://blog.programster.org/set-up-a-local-ubuntu-mirror-with-apt-mirror - I have tested this in my scenario of "zones".

I hope all other installs are reasonably clear to you?  I can edit and put an extract of the manual linked above, if more details needed.

## EDIT: Memorandum (July 10th, 2023)

I am writing this in order to update the info on the size of my current mirror in `/var/spool/apt-mirror`.  But since the moment in history is a bit nostalgic, as Ubuntu Bionic has just "retired", I have decided to add this memorandum:  it is the time to close this chapter of admin's life, with Ubuntu Bionic.  End-of-Life for Ubuntu Bionic (version 18.04 LTE) has been reached on May 31st, 2023.  Ubuntu LTE covers 5 years of updates, Ubuntu Pro (non-free) covers 10 years of support.

**Repo size**: As of today, all of the repos: `main restricted universe multiverse` of `bionic bionic-security bionic-updates` of both: `deb-i386` and `deb-src` all use up **241 GB** of disk space.

**Last 32-bit Ubuntu**: The version 18.04 is the last Ubuntu to support i386 architecture.  All newer versions will not work on 32 bit machines.  Now is the last chance to obtain install images and the repo if you are a fan of Ubuntu and would like to keep Bionic installable, for fun :)  For other 32-bit Linux distros see a list on [itsfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/)

**Key configs**: Below are parts in `/etc/atc/mirror.list` that are responsible for obtaining Bionic's repos.  (Some other defaults are also needed there, which shall be already in place in newer versions of Ubuntu.)

```
set defaultarch  i386

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Comment: Legend, much appreciated mate! should be good for the rest!

Comment: Not sure if you can assist here again mate, but i'm looking for a similar solution but with a docker registry.

Comment: It's best if you file a new ticket;  this would also attract other people (by the title and by the creation date) and certainly many people who come accross your question will be those who have just done what you have in mind.